# A simple encryption idea from a String ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, char

I have a given String ArrayList. Using the elements in the ArrayList, I wanted to create a string. The string is obtained by displaying the characters in a column, inserting a space, and then displaying the next column and inserting a space, and so on. For example, the array list as follows :

> [stac, kove, rflo, w]

My string should be the first letter of the first element and first letter of the second element (finish the array elements) and space, then second letter of the first element and second letter of the second element and so on. The result should be:

> skrw tof avl ceo

Here is the closest code that I had:

```
public static String display(ArrayList<String> words){
    String s = "";
    for(int i=0; i<words.size(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<words.get(i).length(); j++){
            s += words.get(i).charAt(j) + " ";  
        }

    }
    return s;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you **not** want the spaces in your string?

Comment: just remove the + " " and add the space after the inner loop

Comment: I want spaces. "My string should be the first letter of the first element and first letter of the second element (finish the array elements) and space, then second letter of the first element and second letter of the second element and so on."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the function match the output that you want:

```
public static String display(ArrayList<String> words) {
    String s = "";
    int index = 0;
    boolean hit = false;
    while (!hit) {
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            String w = words.get(i);
            if (w.length() > index) {
                s += w.charAt(index);
                hit = true;
            }
        }           
        if (hit) {
            hit = false;
            index++;
            s += " ";
        } else {
            hit = true;
        }

    }
    return s.trim();
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks!